# Using require in a function causes bundle size to increase by 200%

Tags: webpack, vue.js

In my Vue + Webpack project previous build, the dist folder js files size was just 4 Mb.

I added a new function  and run build again, now the bundle size increased to 12 Mb.

The function has this line

`chapterselected = require('assets/json/ml/' + chapterfile + '.xml.json')`

in it, if i comment this line the bundle will be 4mb again,

```
search() {
   /// some codes
   chapterselected = require('assets/json/ml/' + chapterfile + '.xml.json')
   /// process chapterselected here
},
```

I cannot remove this line as its main part of the function so i need help to solve this problem - why is it increasing the bundle size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's putting every file in that folder, `assets/json/ml/`, in your bundle. Presumably those are large files.

If your Javascript file is too big, I would pass `*.json` files to the file loader, not json loader, so that they're loaded over the network at runtime. It will still put all the large json files in your output folder, but it will only load what's needed at runtime.

Comment: i have alredy one another function which is using the same method to load json files

Comment: let me check whether i can use the same function here

Comment: yes, this worked, i could reuse the existing function to call require()

Comment: If this answered your question, click the empty checkmark next to it to mark it as correct to help others